# Google Admin SDK enterprise enrollment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, chromebook, google-admin-settings-api

Is there a way to enroll chromebooks using Google Apps Script.

[Here are the steps Google gives](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1360534?hl=en), but I want to automated the process. I couldn't find any documentation on enterprise enrollment in the the admin sdk. We've already accepted the terms of agreement. And now we have a new batch of chromebooks that need to be enrolled.

> Turn on the device and follow the on-screen instructions until you see the sign-in screen. Don't sign in yet. If you see the enrollment screen instead of the sign-in screen, go to Step 4.

> If you're enrolling a Chromebook tablet, tap Email or phone. Then, tap More More and then Switch to full layout to open the on-screen keyboard.

> Choose an option to get to the enrollment screen:

> Press Ctrl+Alt+E.

> Click More options and then Enterprise enrollment (not available on Chromebook tablets).

> Enter the username and password from your Google admin welcome letter or for a Google Account that has eligibility to enroll.

> If prompted, enter the asset ID and location and click Next.

> When you get a confirmation message that the device is successfully enrolled, click Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to use Admin SDK to enroll chromebooks as you need to enter commands and username/password information from the chromebook itself.

The official workaround provided by Google is to use a [Rubber Ducky](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9412749?hl=en&ref_topic=9028498#zippy=)
device to automate keystrokes.